# Why user data is not checked and re-resigter in database reactjs and php

Tags: php, mysql, reactjs, forms, authentication

I make a signup and login form in react js and php.

Problem is that my php code note check that user is already registered, the insertion is doing well but for all new and registered users. And the same problem occurs in login system, that it does not check if user is registered so it can be logged in.

Here is my php code :

```
<?php

require('DbConnect.php');

header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://127.0.0.1:5173");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Content-Type");
header("Content-Type: application/json");

$postdata = file_get_contents('php://input'); 
if(isset($postdata) && !empty($postdata)){
    $request = json_decode($postdata);

    $name = $request->name;
    $email = $request->email;
    $password = $request->password;
    $view =$request->view;

    $Sql = "SELECT * 
            FROM registration 
            WHERE name = '$name' 
            AND email = '$email' 
            AND view = '$view'";
    $exeSQL = mysqli_query($db, $Sql);
    $check =  mysqli_fetch_assoc($exeSQL);

    if($email==isset($check['email'])) {
        echo "email already exists";
    }
    if($name==isset($check['name'])) {
        echo "username  already exists";
    } else {
        $InsertQuery = "INSERT INTO registration
                                (name,email,password,view) 
                        VALUES ('$name','$email','$password','$view')";

        if(mysqli_query($db,$InsertQuery)){
            echo "Complete--!";
        } else {
            echo"Error";
        }
    }
}
?>
//I also tried this method 

if ($checkEmail) {
    if($checkEmail['email']==='$email'){
        array_push($errors, "Email Already registered");    }
        echo "Already registered";
    }
}
```

Here's my reactjs code

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';

const Register = () =>
{
  let navigate = useNavigate();

  const [ data, setData ] = useState( {
    name: "",
    email: "",

    password: "",
    view: " ",
    formUpErrors: {email: '', password: ''}, // ce champ sert a afficher un mesage d'erreur de validation 
    emailValid: false,
    passwordValid: false,
    formValid: false 
  } )
  // const onViewChange = ( value ) =>
  // {
  
  // }
  const change = ( e ) =>
  {
    setData( { ...data, [ e.target.name ]: e.target.value } );
  };


  const submit = ( e ) =>
  {
    e.preventDefault();
    var checkEmail = RegExp(/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/i);
    if ((data.email.length==0) || (data.password.length==0) ){
      alert("Required Field Is Missing!!!");
    }else if (!(checkEmail).test(data.email)){
      alert("invalid email!!!");
    }
    // Password validations
    else if (data.password.length<8){
      alert("Minimum 08 characters required!!!");
    }else if (!((/[ `!@#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?~]/).test(data.password))){
      alert("Use atleast 01 special character!!!");
    }else if (((/[ ]/).test(data.password))){
      alert("Don't include space in password!!!");
    
    }
   
//main part for signing
else {
    axios.post( 'http://localhost/pms/signup.php', data )
      .then( ( responce ) =>
      {
       if ( responce.data = true )
       {
        e.target.reset();
         navigate( '/login' );
         console.log( 'Record SuccessFully Inserted' );
        }
        else
        {
          alert( 'Already registered' );
        }
      
      } );   
  };
}
  return (

  
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row  justify-content-center align-items-center">
         
             
              <div className="row justify-content-center">
              <h1 className="text-center h1 fw-bold mb-3 mx-1 mx-md-4 mt-2">Registration</h1>
                  <div className="col-md-10 col-lg-6 col-xl-5 order-2 order-lg-1">
       <form className="mx-auto mx-md-4" onSubmit={submit}>
<div className="card mx-auto my-2 px-4 py-3">
                      <div className="d-flex flex-row align-items-center mb-2">
                        <i className="fas fa-user fa-lg me-3 fa-fw"></i>
                        <div className="form-outline flex-fill mb-0">
                        <label className="form-label" htmlFor="form3Example1c">Name</label>
                  <input type="text" id="form3Example1c" className="form-control" name='name' onChange={change} value={data.name} required placeholder='Enter name' />
                          
                        </div>
                      </div>

                      <div className="d-flex flex-row align-items-center mb-2">
                        <i className="fas fa-envelope fa-lg me-3 fa-fw"></i>
                        <div className="form-outline flex-fill mb-0">
                        <label className="form-label" htmlFor="form3Example3c">Email</label>
                  <input type="email" id="form3Example3c" className="form-control" name='email' value={data.email} onChange={change} required placeholder='Enter email '/>
                          
                        </div>
                      </div>

                      <div className="d-flex flex-row align-items-center mb-2">
                        <i className="fas fa-lock fa-lg me-3 fa-fw"></i>
                        <div className="form-outline flex-fill mb-0">
                        <label className="form-label" htmlFor="form3Example4c">Password</label>
                          <input type="password" id="form3Example4c" className="form-control" name='password'value={data.password} onChange={change} required placeholder='choose a password'/>
                       </div>
                      </div>

                      <div className=" d-flex flex-row align-items-center mb-2">
                      <i className="fas fa-lock fa-lg me-3 fa-fw"></i>
                        <div className="form-outline flex-fill mb-0">
                        <label className="form-label" htmlFor='form3Example5c'>Occupation  </label><br/>
                          <select className="select form-control" id='form3Example5c' required value={data.view} onChange={change} name='view'>
                    <option value="" >Choose option</option>
                    <option value="SuperVisor">SuperVisor</option>
                    <option value="Student">Student</option>
                    {/* <option value="4">Subject 3</option> */}
                  </select>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                     

                      <div className="d-flex justify-content-center mx-4 mb-3 mb-lg-4 mt-3">
                <button type="button submit" className="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Submit</button>
                <button type="button submit" className="btn btn-primary btn ms-3" >Reset</button>
                      </div>
                      </div>
                    </form>

                  </div>
                  <div className="col-md-10 col-lg-6 col-xl-7 d-flex align-items-center order-1 order-lg-2">

                    <img src="https://mdbcdn.b-cdn.net/img/Photos/new-templates/bootstrap-registration/draw1.webp"
                        className="img-fluid" alt="Sample image" />
                     

                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
      
  )
}

export default Register
```

I tried that my signup form check the userdata is already registered and show alert.

Comment: Good code indentation and layout would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187)
You should always use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) 
in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenating user provided values into the query. Never trust ANY user input!
This will also remove the unescaped character issue like a `'` in a text string like `O'Neal'.

Comment: You need to check what `isset()` does in the [PHP Manula](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php). ___HINT___ It returns a boolean

Answer (score 1):

These 2 IF's will not do what you think they are doing as `isset()` returns a boolean and when you compare true with any string it will be true

EG

```
echo 'a string' == true ? 'YES true' : 'NO true';
```

will output `YES true` So as long as there is anything in the string it will be true.

So change these lines

```
    if($email==isset($check['email'])) {
        echo "email already exists";
    }
    if($name==isset($check['name'])) {
        echo "username  already exists";
```

to

```
    if(isset($check['email']) && $check['email'] == $email) {
        echo "email already exists";
    }
    if(isset($check['name']) && $check['name'] == $email) {
        echo "username  already exists";
```

Comment: Please describe in what way it is not working. Can you also show me the output from `var_export($postdata);`